# How to make comparison report in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I am having  a problem in making a report to show the comparison between  present transaction result  and its future impact result

i am using vb.net and i am displaying  the report using the values in the data table  and so far  my data table shows record like this.
In this record  f_id  = 1 in both  purchase  and sale transaction and it will increment  on both  if there are more transaction.
I have to display the purchase transaction  which has f_id = 1 on the left and other  on the right side.Image 3 will tells you what am trying to say 
[image: data table result]

currently my reports are displaying like this 
[image: old report style]

but i want to display the report in this style  so that its much more easier to compare between the two. 
[image: New report style]
    here is my code that prints the data on the  report

```
Private Sub FutureTransaction()

    Dim sql = "SELECT client.cl_cname, company.co_sname, invmast.im_qty, invmast.im_rate, invmast.im_tdate,invmast.im_crate,invmast.im_tax,invmast.f_type,invmast.f_id"
    Sql += " FROM invmast "
    sql += "INNER JOIN company ON invmast.co_scode = company.co_scode "
    sql += "INNER JOIN  client ON invmast.cl_ccode = client.cl_ccode  and"
    sql += " invmast.fn_code = client.fn_code"
    sql += " where invmast.im_tdate>='" & dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "' and invmast.im_tdate <= '" & dtpToDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'"
    sql += " and invmast.f_type = 1 and im_qty > 0"
    sql += "ORDER BY invmast.f_id"

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnMain)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim rpt As New FutureTransaction

    'Dim rptt As New FutureTransaction()
    rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("FundName").Text = "'" & FundName & "'"
    rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("FromDate").Text = "'" & dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'"
    rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("ToDate").Text = "'" & dtpToDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'"
    rpt.Refresh()
    frmReportViewer.crvMain.ReportSource = rpt
    frmReportViewer.crvMain.Refresh()
    frmReportViewer.Show()

End Sub
```

So hope you guys will help me out.

Comment: take two sub reports one for buy place it to the left and one for sell place it to the right on the design

Comment: Siva. If i take two sub reports as you said , will i have to make any changes in the query or data table or just the same result of datatable will display seprately on both  means one on left and one on the right

Comment: As per your convinence...pass saperate data for buy for one sub report  and sell for another sub report...for your info this will speed up the report else pass the same data table for both sub report..this can slow the report